# Show selection of products by ID's

Tags: category, product-list, catalogsearch

We need to show to customers a list or products that are in the same category, but we don't want to list other products of that category.

Specific example:
We have a categories "t-shirts" and we want to link from a banner to all t-shirts that contain "Mickey Mouse". We have the ID's of the products from the backend of course.

Is there a way or an extension to achieve this?

Sth. like ../index.php?products=1,7,11,13?

If there is no solution out of the box, how would you achieve this programmatically? Using the standard listing/grid of the shop (same templates).

Comment: you could use widgets of type "Catalog Product Link", but there its only possible to enter one product...

Comment: thx roman for the idea. our use case is to have links, that could even be sent around and limit the product list to the product id's passed via GET

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for extension, you can search for **landing pages** module at the magento connect. Basically there are some, and at least one allows to define products SKUs , category or/and attribute conditions.

If you want to create your own plugin, you need to define a new custom block, extended from the `Mage_Catalog_Product_List` with the modified function `getProductCollection()`, where you can add you conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Sander and the gang build a great landing page with layered navigation extension, you can find it here:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/layered-landing

You can't filter by id but a lot of other attributes.